# MacBook Pro 13" Install DVD Wont Start

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, macbook

Excuse such a basic question... I am a Laptop Fixer and deal with Windows based laptops only but very recently took in a 13" MacBook Pro for a re-install of the OS (easy I thought!)

I inserted the Install DVD, held the C button and turn on.  I could hear the disk spinning up and after about a min the DVD is ejected.  There are a few scratches on the DVD but should be ok as not that deep.

However, Windows Vista was installed (it failed to install properly hence the re-install of Mac OS).  Should I wipe clean and format the hard disk first?  Could this be the reason the DVD is ejected?

Any advice would be gratefully accepted?

p.s. never held a MacBook Pro before... first impressions, wow... alu casing and massive touch pad... and the magnetic power socket....  so impressed and it doesn't even work!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, try holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key when rebooting. If you don't see the OS X install DVD as a startup disk option, you can confirm bad media. You did not mention how Vista was installed...assuming that was from a DVD, you can rule out the Combo-Drive being the issue.
Next thing to do ( if you have acccess to one ) is to boot the MBP from an external HD that has OS X already installed. Double check to see if you can mount the OS X insatall DVD in the Finder...if not, perhaps contact Apple about replacing the DVD media.

Comment: There was a dell OEM vista DVD in the drive which took a bit of searching to find how to remove it!!!! but hold the touchpad down on a restart did it! 

I will try the option key.  

Please bear with me as this is the first time I have used a Mac!!! I have a suspicion the cd may be too scratched..